# Kinect on Mathematica

Tags: hardware

I saw on the internet a lot of nice experiments with Microsoft Kinect. I just bought one and would like to know if someone here has been able to use it with Mathematica.

The main idea is to been able to use it as another controller device. So you could get it state using `Dynamic@ControllerState` Mathematica command. In some way, it's necessary to install a driver that make this possible.

I installed zigfu and synapse-kinect on my mac (see links below). They demo worked just nice, but no additional device appeared on my Mathematica. You can list connected devices using the `ControllerInformation[]` command.

[image]

Here are some links with potential starting points, as suggested in the comments:

http://zigfu.com/en/downloads/browserplugin/

http://www.shiffman.net/p5/kinect/

http://developkinect.com/resource/application/synapse-kinect

http://glovepie.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=32

Comment: There's definitely no built-in support. Nothing is stopping you from using .NET/Link though.

Comment: I sow in google people trying to use .NET/Link, but without success.

Comment: +1. I had that idea too but ran out of capacity to start another project. Have a look at Daniel Shiffman's page on Kinect and Processing. http://www.shiffman.net/p5/kinect/ it should be fairly straight forward to call the processing framework from Mathematica.

Comment: Sjoerd said he has had success connecting to his Wii using mma and getting data out of it. He might be able to explain the steps required, which you can then try with kinect

Comment: Yep, see [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2986/57). It appears that the software (GlovePIE) I used for the Wiimote now also supports Kinect. I noticed that the frontpage of the GlovePIE website is currently hacked, other parts (the [blog](http://glovepie.org/blog) and the [forum](http://glovepie.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=32)) are still available.

Comment: @Matariki tks for the link. I have already make it works on my Mac using [ynapse-kinect](http://developkinect.com/resource/application/synapse-kinect), but not in MM yet.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I'll study the GlovePIE to see what it's possible. tks

Comment: I don't think GlovePIE is available for Mac.

Comment: I can test in Windows too.

Comment: This program looks very complete, but I don't have enough skills to implement this at the moment. See the link here [zigfu](http://zigfu.com/en/downloads/browserplugin/)

Comment: If you're interested in Kinect you might also be interested in [Leap motion](https://leapmotion.com/).

Comment: Yes!.. it's fantastic. I have pre ordered 2 in the begin of the year!

Comment: @0xFE I do think there's support for that according to this http://devices.wolfram.com/devices/microsoft-kinect.html

Comment: I have tried to use https://falahati.net/my-projects/95-openni-2-virtual-webcam-v0-9-directshow-filter-for-openni which allows you to make the Kinect Depth sensor appear like a normal Webcam for programs that use DirectShow to query webcams (e.g. Skype). But it looks like Mathematica does not use Webcams in this way, at least I could not get it to work...

Comment: From what I understand, the device should be listed under `$ImagingDevices`, not `ControllerInformation[]` (my normal webcam does not appear there). `FindDevices` should also be possible. In fact, that should probably be the route to go, see tutorial/DevelopingDeviceDrivers in the documentation.